# Determining minimum values in a vector in R

Tags: r

I need some help in determining more than one minimum value in a vector. Let's suppose, I have a vector x:

```
x<-c(1,10,2, 4, 100, 3)
```

and would like to determine the indexes of the smallest 3 elements, i.e. 1, 2 and 3.  I need the indexes of because I will be using the indexes to access the corresponding elements in another vector. Of course, sorting will provide the minimum values but I want to know the indexes of their actual occurrence prior to sorting.

Comment: How are you deciding that 1, 2, and 3 are the minimums?  Are you just more generally asking how to find the index of values that match values in a different vector?  Or just how to find the 3 smallest values and their indices?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to find the index try this

```
which(x %in% sort(x)[1:3])  # this gives you and index vector
[1] 1 3 6
```

This says that the first, third and sixth elements are the first three lowest values in your vector, to see which values these are try:

```
x[ which(x %in% sort(x)[1:3])]  # this gives the vector of values
[1] 1 2 3
```

or just

```
x[c(1,3,6)]
[1] 1 2 3
```

If you have any duplicated value you may want to select unique values first and then sort them in order to find the index, just like this (Suggested by @Jeffrey Evans in his answer)

```
which(x %in% sort(unique(x))[1:3])
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you mean you want to know what are the indices of the bottom 3 elements? In that case you want `order(x)[1:3]`

Answer (score 3):

You can use unique to account for duplicate minimum values.

```
x<-c(1,10,2,4,100,3,1)
which(x %in% sort(unique(x))[1:3])
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way with `rank` that includes duplicates.

```
 x <- c(x, 3)
 # [1]   1  10   2   4 100   3   3
 which(rank(x, ties.method='min') <= 3)
 # [1] 1 3 6 7
```