# Get first n indexes fulfilling a condition in r

Tags: r

I have a large vector where I have different values. I would like to find first N values which are less than a particular value.

For example in the following vector I want only 3 indexes which are less than 3

```
x2 <- c(1.6,0.35,1,3,6,8,1.5,2)
x3 <- which(x2 < 3)
x3
[1] 1 2 3 7 8
```

From X3 I can extract the first three values but they are not the smallest values in the vector. If I order the X2 vector before applying the condition, I am loosing the indexes of the values. What I want at the end is as follows

```
[1] 2 3 7
```

Comment: Are you looking for the indices of the smallest three values in the vector?

Comment: @CactusWoman: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: This will probably answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458702/determining-minimum-values-in-a-vector-in-r

Comment: @CactusWoman Thanks for the reply. But I also would like to add a condition for getting the first n indexes. If the condition is not fulfilled by n values I get only the values which are fulfilled by the condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `rank` function is what you are looking for:

```
which(rank(x2)<=3 & x2<3)
#[1] 2 3 7
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
match(sort(x2[x2 < 3])[1:3], x2)
#[1] 2 3 7
```

We can match the smallest 3 values less than the threshold to the original vector.

**edit**

This will work with unique and non-unique vectors

```
which(!is.na(match(x2, sort(x2[x2 < 3])[1:3]))) 
[1] 2 3 7
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this doesn't work if the vector is not unique.

Comment: I updated. But I think @nicola's is more to the point. Choose that one.